# Having problem in printing butterfly pattern with stars in java

Tags: java

```
public static void butterFly(int n){
    //Outer loop
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        // star - i
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
        //Spaces - 2 * (n - i)
        for(int j = 1; j <= 2*(n-i); j++){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        //Stars - i
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    // 2nd half
    //Outer loop
    for(int i = n; i >= 1; i--){
        // star - i
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
        //Spaces - 2 * (n - i)
        for(int j = 1; j <= 2*(n-i); j++){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        //Stars - i
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

```
*         * 
* *       * *
* * *     * * *
* * * *   * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * *   * * * *
* * *     * * *
* *       * *
*         *
```

I was expecting this

```
         *      *
         **    **    
         ***  ***     
         ********       
         ***  ***      
         **    **     
         *      *
```

I have breaked my code into 2 parts 1st half of butterfly and second half of butterfly .
For print stars i have taken the value j =i where i is less then equals to n which is user input.
for printing spaces i have taken the j <= 2*(n-i).
and for the 2nd part i just reversed the outer loop.

Comment: You must print more spaces

Answer (score 1):

You should remove spaces after *, i.e., `System.out.print("* ")`; should be `System.out.print("*");`

Also, if you do not want the middle row to be duplicated, start the second half from `n - 1`, not `n`.

```
    //Outer loop
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        // star - i
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        //Spaces - 2 * (n - i)
        for(int j = 1; j <= 2*(n-i); j++){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        //Stars - i
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    // 2nd half
    //Outer loop
    for(int i = n - 1; i >= 1; i--){
        // star - i
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        //Spaces - 2 * (n - i)
        for(int j = 1; j <= 2*(n-i); j++){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        //Stars - i
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```